# How to install laravel on xampp?

Tags: arch-linux, php, manjaro, php5, xampp

I'm using the latest version of manjaro 64 bit and latest version of xampp. I want to install composer and laravel; I tried many solutions on stackoverflow and askubuntu. Every time I see a different error, like openssl and phar are missing and stuff like that. But in fact nothing is missing; I enabled them from `php.ini`

So are there any manjaro user/archer who got Laravel to work on xampp? How?

**Edit**

`php -i | grep ini` outputs

```
▶ php -i | grep ini                                                    
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/mcrypt.dll' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/mcrypt.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_openssl.dll' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_phar.dll' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_phar.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /opt/lampp/etc
Loaded Configuration File => /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
Supported handlers => gdbm cdb cdb_make inifile flatfile 
init_command_executed_count => 0
init_command_failed_count => 0
com_init_db => 0
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException
open sourced by => Epinions.com
PHPRC => /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
$_SERVER['PHPRC'] => /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
```

1. [This is exactly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604522/install-composer-and-configure-with-xampp) how I installed composer. I did what both
   answers said
2. My [/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini](http://pastebin.com/SEVR0W78) as you can see, everything needed is loaded.
3. This [php-mcrypt is installed](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/php-mcrypt/), it comes with its own php version but I'm not using that, I'm using Xampp's version
4. I'm using newest version of xampp 64 bit, the one that comes with PHP 7, same issue with previous versions.
5. In my zshrc I have

> ```
> export PHPRC=/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini 
> export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin
> ```

If I manage to correctly load openssl, mcrypt and phar, I think all my problems will be solved. Composer seems to install without problems but issues start to pop up when I install laravel. It also installs without problems but displays warnings shown above.

Comment: I probably won't be able to help you but; your question needs a little more context. What have you tried? What do the console logs say?

Comment: bounty will expire soon, no answer?